# CSS - How to put a space every 3 characters in a form input?

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I have this form for registering a new account and I would like to format the phone number input to look like ***911 111 111*** instead of ***911111111*** with some sort of automatic spacing css thingy.. is it possible?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
let getInput1 = document.querySelector("input")
getInput1.addEventListener("keypress", (event) =>{
    if(event.key == " "){
       event.preventDefault();
    }
});

setInterval(() => {
    /* The html reference to the phone number field */
    let getInput = document.querySelector("input").value;

    if(getInput.length == 9) {
        let arrayNumber = [];

         x = 1;
        for(let index = 0; index < getInput.length; index++) {
            arrayNumber[index] = getInput[index];
            if(x % 3 === 0) {
                arrayNumber[index] = getInput[index] + " ";
            }
            x++;
        }


        document.querySelector("input").value = arrayNumber.join("");
        /* Code written by anti-Illuminati armed forces section H.K.A */

    }
}, 100);
```

You can't do it in CSS, you need code JAVASCRIPT have given below my own

Comment: event.preventDefault()? when will you stop breaking my keyboard?! Just show an error message explaining the problem instead of making me check the keyboard cable.